# Control chrome with ternimal

Tags: google-chrome

I want to name my page, for example,

[image]

If I create a group (Github), and I hope I can do something like

> `group <group-id> [sub-id]`

| cmd | desc |
| --- | --- |
| `group Github` | if ignore the `sub-id` open the first item |
| `group Github Page1` | open the Page1 |
| `group Github page2` | open the page2 |

And I hope the regular tab(not in the group, still works). For example, I create a standard page, assign an ID to it, and then do as below.

> `favorite <my-page-id>`

---

It's pretty similar to this extension.

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-control-for-chro/mhofehfbkjmeldlgkbleegeffhaocceg?hl=en

but I hope I do some modify

---

I don't mind using other languages to implement. I can accept `Golang`, `Python`, `JS`. If there are similar open-source projects, you are welcome to share. Thank you!

### Reference

The below link maybe help you answer.

- [Control Chrome completely with the keyboard](https://superuser.com/q/334210/1093221)
- [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts%2Caddress-bar-shortcuts%2Cwebpage-shortcuts%2Cmouse-shortcuts%2Ctab-and-window-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/) by myself.

Below is the link. You can download and try.

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console/nbjjflbnekmabedahdolabcpahfjojjb

---

Technically it is not the same as my request, but it can help you find the tab.

You can use the bookmark, create a directory, and put the things you usually visit in it.

And create an input that supports autocomplete and regular expression to find specific tabs easier.

You can reference [w3school-autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) as the base and do some modifications.

---

If you really want to use the group, you can try `groupID`

> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab <sup>[permalink-chrome-version:93.0.4577.70](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/a63811570d1f34df2f348de6088394bdc92dbe54/chrome/common/extensions/api/tabs.json#L54)</sup>